# How to convert contents of a very large text file into json?

Tags: javascript, json

For eg,

Supposed I have a particular line in a text file that has the following pattern:

```
紅火 红火 [hong2 huo3] /prosperous/
```

I want this to be converted as follows:

```
{ "simplified": 紅火, "traditional": 红火, "pinyin": hong2 huo3, "english": /prosperous/ }
```

The file can be huge like in MB.

And I want to accomplish this using Javascript if possible...

Comment: Your desired output isn't actually valid JSON. (The values need to be double-quoted too.)

Comment: Has this textfile been sent via XHR to the browser where the conversion from text to json will occur?  Or will the jsonify occur on the server? Is the text file's pattern absolutely consistent?

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to retain the slashes in the converted English form?  Why would you want `"english": "/prosperous/"` and not `"english" : "prosperous"`?

Comment: My apologies.  I couldn't remember the exact format of what JSON supposed to look.  But the core context of my questions is I do want a JSON formatted data coming off from a text file.  It's just a small technicality.  Tim - jsonify will occur on the server preferably.  My idea behind this getup is to have a user input english or chinese characters on text field, and when he does the translation, the search algorithm goes through all the text file content and fetches all relevant translations and store them into json and hands the result back to the user on the front end.